# What is the file `modules.txt` in Prestashop at the root directory for?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

What is the file `modules.txt` in Prestashop at the root directory for ?

Is it safe to delete it or is it necessary for Prestahop to work ?

Comment: Which version ? Because I didn't see any modules.txt on Prestashop tree files or github
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/1.6.1.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supposed to be here actually. I have checked on 1.5 to 1.7. You should make a security check.

Comment: Thank you. It looks inoffensive, and I found it somewhere on github in an old prestshop fork (https://github.com/cizi/prestaShop/blob/master/modules.txt). So I know I'll delete it.